# How can I tell Spring to scan for a given annotation without annotating that annotation with @Component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a collection of classes which I want to be injected into the Spring application context. However, these classes can only be guaranteed to be annotated with one of a group of annotations I have written - i.e. I can assume it will be annotated with @MyAnnotation, but not @Component.

However, @MyAnnotation forms part of an API for my project, and I don't want to state an explicit dependency of this API on Spring. Thus, I can't annotate @MyAnnotation with @Component in order to have it be transitively picked up by Spring.

Is there a way to tell Spring to additionally include @MyAnnotation in its classpath scanning without adding this dependency to my API?

Currently I'm manipulating the bean definition registry to 'manually' add each class annotated with @MyAnnotation, but I'd prefer to rely on Spring's inbuilt support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you already loading them into the context manually with the BeanDefinationProcessor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible if you create your own [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) to register your own beans.  If you implement the `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` method, you can add beans to the registry by yourself, for example:

```java
@Component
public class FooFactoryBean implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(..);
    }
}
```

To obtain these bean definitions, you can use the [`ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) class, which will create `BeanDefinition` objects for all classes found for a specific filter. In this case, an `AnnotationTypeFilter` will work:

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Foo.class));
Set<BeanDefinition> definitions = scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.example.my");
```

In this example, it will find all classes annotated with `@Foo` in the `com.example.my` package.

Answer (score 0):

`@Configuration` classes and XML based configuration should work for you. Have a look at this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

But to get your `@MyAnnotation`s picked up is more difficult (see @g00glen00b's answer), and I'm not sure it makes sense if the above mentioned solutions are available.

Comment: Similar to having no control over whether `@Component` is added to a given class I wish to be picked up, I also have no control over whether a class is wrapped in a bean method within a `@Configuration` class.

The classes annotated with `@MyAnnotation` are written by a consumer of my library. I can guarantee it will be annotated with `@MyAnnotation`, but the consumer should not have to write a method to add the class to the application context themselves. This should be handled transparently by `@MyAnnotation`.